# How to display all nodes on screen in neo4j

Tags: neo4j

I have a almost 5000 nodes of `Recipes` and 5 nodes of `Meal_Types` in neo4j database. Right now there is no relationship between them. I am running CQL below:

`MATCH (n) RETURN n LIMIT 100000`

This is running fine, but it is returning node related to `Recipes` only. There may be something hidden, I mean there might be nodes related to `Meal_Types` but as they are in same color it is very hard to differentiate them.

So is there a way to bring all nodes to dispaly with different colors respectively?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can change the styling of the output in the neo4j browser as described here:

https://neo4j.com/developer/guide-neo4j-browser/#_styling_neo4j_browser_visualization

However, there is a limit for the number of nodes/relationships that can be displayed. So you will likely not see all 5000 `Recipe` nodes and all 5 `Meal_Type` nodes but rather the first N nodes returned from your query.

Rendering of large graphs is really difficult :)

Answer (score 36):

Since you write about "display" and "colors", I assume you're writing about the Neo4j browser.

Your query might limit its results to the first 100000, but the browser will actually display much less nodes, with a default number of 300. You can change that value using the following command in the browser:

```
:config initialNodeDisplay: 1000
```

or through the settings pane on the bottom left (see the "Graph Visualization" section).

Since you only have 5 `Meal_Types` nodes, vs 5000 `Repices`, it's unlikely they'll be part of any partial result. You can bias the result by ordering on the label, since `Meal_Type` will sort alphabetically before `Recipes`:

```
MATCH (n)
RETURN n
ORDER BY head(labels(n))
LIMIT 300
```

That way, you don't need to display more nodes (since you can't zoom out, it's pretty useless anyway) and you'll always get your 5 `Meal_Types`.