# neo4j - How to bring all nodes of one type in a result of relationship query?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am sorry for the stupid question. I have two types of nodes in neo4j database, namely `Recipes` and `Meal_Type`. I am running a cypher query in neo4j that results all relationship between the two types of nodes. The query is not that special, it is the default query that returns relationship with a limit of 200 nodes.

`MATCH ()-[r]->() RETURN r LIMIT 200`

It is running fine. But I need, at least, all `Meal_Types` nodes in result regardless the rest of result. Right now it is returning 3 (sometimes 4,5 on re-running query) out of 11 `Meal_Types`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should fetch all of the `Meal_Type` nodes first and then with that result fetch a set of `Recipe` nodes that correspond to it.

Here is an example of what I am talking about.  Fetch all of the different meal types, unless of course you have some specific ones you are interested in.  Then with those meal types return a sampling of the corresponding set of recipes (200 ~= 19 * 11).

```
// match meal types
MATCH (mt:Meal_Type)
WITH mt
// find a sampling of the the corresponding recipes.
MATCH (mt)<-[OF_TYPE]-(r:Recipe)
RETURN mt, collect(r)[0..18] AS recipe_sample
```

Comment: `match (mt:Meal_Type) with mt match (mt)` --> `match (mt:Meal_Type)` or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Really? I answered [that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38503293/1350869) yesterday with your previous question, it's just a variation.

This should do the trick, sorting the relationships by node label:

```
MATCH (n)-[r]-()
RETURN r
ORDER BY head(labels(n))
```